# Returning a Static Local Reference

Tags: c++, coding-style, static, reference, return-value

Suppose I have a function that will return a large data structure, with the intention that the caller will immediately copy the return value:

```
Large large()
{
    return Large();
}
```

Now suppose I do not want to rely on any kind of compiler optimizations such as return value optimization etc. Also suppose that I cannot rely on the C++11 move constructor. I would like to gather some opinions on the "correctness" of the following code:

```
const Large& large()
{
    static Large large;
    large = Large();
    return large;
}
```

It should work as intended, but is it poor style to return a reference to a static local even if it is const qualified?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. In the hypothetical you describe, the first way is still correct.

Comment: @Rob Ultimately I want the speed of returning a reference without making the caller responsible for memory management and without making assumptions about my compiler.

Comment: In that case, no your second example is not "correct". You have one copy operation inside `large()` and what I presume is another in `large()`'s caller. In the case of a poorly-optimizing compiler, your hand-"optimized" code is no faster than the code it replaces. In the case of an optimizing compiler, it is slower. In either case, it is more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Rob Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what *should work as expected* means. In this case all callers will share references to the exact same variable. Also note that if callers will copy, then you are effectively disabling RVO (Return Value Optimization), which *will work* in all current compilers <sup>[*]</sup>.

I would stay away from that approach as much as possible, it is not idiomatic and will probably cause confusion in many cases.

<sup>[*]</sup>The calling convention in all compilers I know of determines that a function that returns a *large* (i.e. does not fit a register) variable receives a hidden pointer to the location in which the caller has allocated the space for the variable. That is, the *optization* is forced by the calling convention.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any issue with doing this.  So long as this code base is, and forever will be, single threaded.

Do this on a multithreaded piece of code, and you might never be able to figure out why your data are occasionally being randomly corrupted.