# Can a function safely return a reference to an internal static variable?

Tags: c++

Is it valid when a function returns by reference its own internal static variable?

```
const int& f() {
    static int n=10;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a Static Local Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133965/returning-a-static-local-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with this. In particular, the static variable *isn't* destroyed when the function exits, so it doesn't return a dangling reference (as it would if `n` was not static).

Just keep in mind that it's a static variable, so for example in this:

```
#include <iostream>

const int& f(int x) {
    static int n;
    n = x;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    const int &a = f(1);
    const int &b = f(2);
    cout << a << " " << b;
}
```

`a` and `b` refer to the same variable, so this prints "2 2" and not "1 2".

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. The static variable will be initialized the first time the function is executed, and will survive beyond the function's return.